What is best HTTP method for Maintenance Web
First, im sorry if my english is not good enough. So yeah, i have a problem with SOA Task in my college.
I want to make a maintenance web service for my web app, but i don't understand what is best method for this service POST, GET, PUT or what? thank you so much for helping me.
My expectation is the maintenance web button direct with cPanel(web hostinger) when it clicked so the programmers can easily access and edit repository

The choice of HTTP methods (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE) depends on the actions you want to perform with your web service:

GET: Typically used for retrieving data from a server. If you need to retrieve information about the repository or any other resources, you might use GET.

POST: Used for creating new resources on the server. If you want to allow programmers to upload or create new files in the repository, you might use POST.

PUT: Used for updating existing resources on the server. If you want to allow programmers to modify existing files in the repository, you might use PUT.

DELETE: Used for deleting resources on the server. If you want to allow programmers to delete files from the repository, you might use DELETE.


